# How to configure Identity Provider (IP-STS) with ADFS?

Tags: adfs2.0

I am attempting to set up a test configuration for IdentityProvider(IP-STS)-Initiated SSO using ADFS 2.0 as my RP STS and a Active Directory identity provider. Here is my set up:

Identity Provider - Domain Active Directy

RP-STS - ADFS 2.0 instance with an RP trust relationship with my asp.net application.

RP Application - ASP.NET web application (WIF) with an STS reference to my ADFS 2.0 STS.

I know I need to create some kind of trust between ADFS and my IP but I don't know what that might be. My issue is I can't find any good resources for instructions on how to do this. Most of what I find assumes that ADFS is also the Identity Provider and is configured. I am not finding the right resources

please any one help me with right example.

Thanks,
sampath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, AD is an IP(Identity Provider).

I've Installed ADFS in one machine(VM), and my Identity Provider(Ipd) is in another VM.

Now **i want to establish trust relationship between these two.**

you are saying **When you install ADFS it "binds" to the AD DC in the domain - that's the trust relationship** means I need to setup ADFS and AD DC in the same machine(VM)?

i have another IP, then how to set up a RP relationship between the two IPs with the normal metadata exchange?

i've added the AD DC as relying party trust in adfs. but getting the following error

***HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
Module IIS Web Core 
Notification MapRequestHandler 
Handler StaticFile 
Error Code 0x80070002 
Requested URL 
Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ClaimsApp_STS\ 
Logon Method Anonymous 
Logon User Anonymous***

Thanks,

Sampath.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "Identity Provider - Domain Active Directory", what IP are you using?

AD is not an IP?

ADFS (which uses AD as its repository) is.

When you install ADFS it "binds" to the AD DC in the domain - that's the trust relationship. You don't need to do anything explicit.

If you indeed have another IP, then you set up a CP / RP relationship between the two IP with the normal metadata exchange.